# Как обрабатывать все представления (views) в проекте одной функцией без дублирования кода?

Tags: django

Это мой первый вопрос, не судите строго. Я нуб)
Есть представление (`views`) в `Django` проекте:

```
def home_view(request):
    if request.GET.get('inv'):
        response = render(request, 'main.html', {})
        response.set_cookie('inv', request.GET.get('inv'), max_age=31536000)
    else:
        response = render(request, 'main.html', {})
    return response
```

Которое, если в запросе есть аргумент `inv`, рендерит шаблон `main.html` и устанавливает `cookies` на год, иначе рендерит шаблон без установки `cookies`.

Но мне эту штучку нужно будет делать для всех въюх проекта. То-есть обращение **к любому `URL`** сайта с параметром `inv` должно обрабатываться. Декораторами городить? Может в `urls.py` есть какая-то фишечка, чтобы направлять все запросы сначала на эту `view`, а потом уже на целевые?

Comment: наследование полиморф передача параметров по ссылке и процедур такого в py нет разве? передайте в home и домашний запрос и целевой домашний выполнится и вызовет целевой

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Есть возможность перехватывать все запросы в промежуточном слое.

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'oplus.middleware.cookie_middleware',  # мой промежуточный слой
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

middleware.py

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse


def cookie_middleware(get_response):

    def middleware(request: HttpRequest):
        response: HttpResponse = get_response(request)
        if request.GET.get('inv'):
            response.set_cookie('inv', request.GET.get('inv'),
                                max_age=31536000)

        return response

    return middleware
```

Всё отлично работает. Теперь обработка идет в промежуточном слое.